# Map to List after filtering on Map's key using Java8 stream

Tags: java, list, java-8, hashmap, collectors

I have a `Map<String, List<String>>`. I want to transform this map to a List after filtering on the map's key.

Example:

```
Map<String, List<String>> words = new HashMap<>();
List<String> aList = new ArrayList<>();
aList.add("Apple");
aList.add("Abacus");

List<String> bList = new ArrayList<>();
bList.add("Bus");
bList.add("Blue");
words.put("A", aList);
words.put("B", bList);
```

Given a key, say, "B"

```
Expected Output: ["Bus", "Blue"]
```

This is what I am trying:

```
 List<String> wordsForGivenAlphabet = words.entrySet().stream()
    .filter(x-> x.getKey().equalsIgnoreCase(inputAlphabet))
    .map(x->x.getValue())
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I am getting an error. Can someone provide me with a way to do it in Java8?

Comment: Well, first off, what error are you getting?

Comment: Why don't you just use `map.get(inputAlphabet.toUpperCase())`?

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner I assume because the `Map` might contains lower case letters also *in general*, this being just an example...

Comment: @Eugene Yes, I also think that this is a simplified example. I just commented so that OP has the chance to improve it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your sniplet wil produce a `List<List<String>>` not `List<String>`.

You are missing [flatMap](https://www.mkyong.com/java8/java-8-flatmap-example/) , that will convert stream of lists into a single stream, so basically flattens your stream:

```
List<String> wordsForGivenAlphabet = words.entrySet().stream()
    .filter(x-> x.getKey().equalsIgnoreCase(inputAlphabet))
    .map(Map.Entry::getValue)
    .flatMap(List::stream) 
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

You can also add `distinct()`, if you don't want values to repeat.

Comment: I am getting "not-static method cannot be referenced from a static context" compilation error on  `.flatMap(List::stream) ` line

Comment: Is your map value of type List,Set? Here words is of Map<String, List<String>> 
 type. What is your words collection type?

Comment: I have Map<String, Object>. I tried the same code as mentioned above and getting the compilation error.

Comment: This Map is coming from another class and I know the values will always be List<String> for a specific key.

Comment: I tried below and it worked. Is it because fo casting?

`List<String> l =  map.entrySet().stream()
            .map(Map.Entry::getValue)
            .filter(c -> c instanceof Collection)
            .map(c -> (Collection<String>)c)
            .flatMap(Collection::stream)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());`

Comment: Yes, it's because of casting. You are doing a safe casting, so it will work.

Answer (score 4):

Federico is right in his comment, if all you want is to get the values of a certain key (inside a `List`) why don't you simply do a `get` (assuming all your keys are uppercase letters already) ?

```
 List<String> values = words.get(inputAlphabet.toUpperCase());
```

If on the other hand this is just to understand how stream operations work, there is one more way to do it (via java-9 `Collectors.flatMapping`)

```
List<String> words2 = words.entrySet().stream()
            .collect(Collectors.filtering(x -> x.getKey().equalsIgnoreCase(inputAlphabet),
                    Collectors.flatMapping(x -> x.getValue().stream(), 
                          Collectors.toList())));
```

Comment: Very nice to use JDK 9 collector's new features

Answer (score 0):

As was previously told after `collect` you will get `List<List<String>>` with only one or zero value in it. You can use `findFirst` instead of `collect` it will return you `Optional<List<String>>`.

Comment: When the map has "B" and "b" as keys, you get only one list.

Comment: Yes, I did not pay attention to `equalsIgnoreCase`, if it is importand my solution won't work properly.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<String> items = words.entrySet().stream()
  .filter(entry -> entry.getKey().equals("B"))
  .flatMap(entry -> entry.getValue().stream())
  .collect(Collectors.toList());
  System.out.println(items);
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, adding a bit of explanation would greatly benefit it, especially for future readers.